# Can we use mongodb on old windows operating systems?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, windows, mern

I have a question that recently I developed a Point Of Sale software using MERN Stack and now my client has a system with specifications, Core I3 2nd Gen with 4gb ram. I installed the latest version of Windows 10 (22H2) on his PC and it slowed down his system. Now I want to install an old windows operating system like Windows 8.1 but I have a question that will I be able to install MongoDb and Node on his operating system. Will it run smoothly on that system? And one more question that I make a version of the POS System and then made a bat file which on run, runs the server locally on machine using "node server.js" command in that folder so is there any way to make it more efficient as well but keep in mind that my main question is that can I use install mongodb on windows 8.1 etc or any other suggestion to run that POS System smoothly like any other operating system which will support mongodb and node js and will run smoothly and I dont have time to change the database as well.

I tried to run the mongodb on latest version of Windows 10 I mean 22H2 but it slowed down the system.

Comment: Core I3 2nd Gen is 12 years old - time for an upgrade. Old MongoDB version 4.4 would be still possible, see [Platform Support](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/administration/production-notes/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.